# How to change the color of a button on Bootstrap and Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

By default the button is red. When the user enters 2 figures for example, the button should turn blue. How can I create this switch on Bootstrap and Angular?

This is in my template:

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-4 text-center" [ngClass]="{'success': otp?.length == 2 ? true : false}">
  <button class="customButton" (click)="signin()">
      ok
  </button>
</div>
```

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6xfea7?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: Please share rest of the code, what you mean by "user enter 2 figures? It  would be gresat if you can create a minimal reproducible example

Comment: why can't you create 2 button and add ngIf based on the condition you provide

Comment: If you make a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) we can more easily help you with your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, here is an idea of my problem please .. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6xfea7?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: You might want to approve changes to your questions and then add the stackblitz link there. Check the comment on my answer for what I did to make your stackblitz work. Cheers

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 : Yes... Sorry, I am approved your modification...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using [class]

In template:

```html
[class.success]="otp?.length === 2"
```

In stylesheet:

```css
.success{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

#### Using [ngClass]

In template:

```html
[ngClass]="{ blue: otp?.length === 2 }"
[ngClass]="getClass()"
```

In component.ts:

```js
getClass() {
  const isLongEnough = otp?.length === 2
  return { success: isLongEnough }
}
```

Or:

```js
getClass() {
  if(otp?.length === 2)
    return 'blue'
  return ''
}
```

Or:

```js
getClass() {
  if(otp?.length === 2)
    return ['blue']
  return []
}
```

#### Using [style]

In template:

```html
[style.color]="'blue'"
```

#### Using [ngStyle]

In template:

```html
[ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': otp?.length === 2 ? 'blue' : 'red' }"
[ngStyle]="getStyle()"
```

In component.ts:

```js
getStyle() : any {
  if(otp?.length === 2)
    return { 'background-color': 'blue' }
  return {}
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote, bootstrap already has its own classes for button colors. But I figured you already read the [docs](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/components/buttons/) and want to use your own color scheme.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help and your explanation. My problem is that I don't understand how to change the color of the button on bootstrap? I edited my code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6xfea7?file=src/app/app.component.html when the user enters 2 figures the button must changer of color...

Comment: If you want only the button to change color, you should put this: **[ngClass]="{'success': otp?.length === 2 ? true : false}"** on the button tag, instead of the wrapping div. And create a css class, e.g.: **.success{ background-color: blue; }** Just those changes, fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try like this?

```
[ngClass]="{'success': otp?.length == 2}"
```